# java - check if a substring is present in an arraylist of strings in java

Tags: java, arraylist

suppose i've an arraylist (arr1) with the following values:

```
"string1 is present"
"string2 is present"
"string3 is present"
"string4 is present"
```

i wanted to see if the substring 'string2' is present in this arraylist. by looping through the arraylist and using 'get' by index i extracted element at each index and then using 'contains' method for 'Strings' i'm searched for 'string2' and found a match

```
for (int i=0;i<arr1.size(); i++)
{
  String s1=arr1.get(i);
  if (s1.contains("string2"))
  {
    System.out.println("Match found");
  }
}
```

is there a way to use the 'contains' method of the arraylist itself and do the same instead of me looping through the arraylist and using the 'contains' method for 'String' to achieve this. Can someone please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `contains` method of `ArrayList`, because you cannot get around checking each string individually.

In Java 8 you can hide the loop by using streams:

```
boolean found = arr1.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.contains("string2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Stream API you could check if the list has an element which contains `"string2"` and print to the console like this:

```
arr1.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.contains("string2"))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(e -> System.out.println("Match found"));
```

However, you *cannot avoid* checking each element individually (until we find the first) because you're interested to see if a particular string contains a specific substring.

Comment: No it would not.  filter(s->s.contains("string2") would.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way (make a string out of the arrayList):

```
String listString = String.join(", ", arr1);

      if (listString.contains("string2"))
      {
        System.out.println("Match found");
      }
```

Comment: This assumes that the search string does not contain commas :-)

Comment: Yes! forgot to mention that. Be careful about it, and if it is with commas, just replace it with an unused character.