# Finding out which ArrayList Number contains my search?

Tags: java, sorting, search, arraylist, contains

I am looking for a method to find out, which place I can find things in an Array List. For example, I have the following list:

```
#0659 Spoon 5
#0234 RGB-Lightning 8
#8453 Watercooling 50
```

Now I want to find out where the RGB-Lightning in the list is. For example, I have got a search like this: `"#0659 Spoon"` Now I want to see which part contains it. I have already tried some things but got `NullPointerException` :(

This code worked as a stand-alone but in my project it didn't (I read in the array list)

```
    int laufvar = -1;

     List<String> haystack = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ABCD", "EFGH", "IJ KL", "M NOP", "UVW X" });
        List<String> needles = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "IJ" });

        // To cut down on iterations, create one big regex to check the whole haystack
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(".*(");
        for (String needle : needles) {
            sb.append(needle).append('|');
        }
        sb.replace(sb.length() - 1, sb.length(), ").*");
        String regex = sb.toString();

        for (String target : haystack) {
            if (!target.matches(regex)) {
                
                laufvar++;
                continue;
            }

            for (String needle : needles) {
                if (target.contains(needle)) {
                    laufvar++;
                    System.out.println(target + " contains " + needle);
                    System.out.println(haystack.get(laufvar));
                    
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that kinda format :(

Comment: show us your code

Comment: I have added it :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java - check if a substring is present in an arraylist of strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48132288/java-check-if-a-substring-is-present-in-an-arraylist-of-strings-in-java)

Comment: Yep. The only difference is that i need to know wich part of the List it is. I need to change something there later on.

Answer (score 0):

you mean:   int id = yourarraylist.indexOf("#0234 RGB-Lightning 8");

Comment: No, I want to know wich of my arraylist contains "#0234 RGB-Lightnint" Cause I dont have the "8" after it.